# Adding in a marker to represent the current position of the user

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am currently using angular and ionic 4 to build a google map interactive map. I currently have multiple markers displaying on the map but am having a bit of a brain fart in trying to figure out how to add in geolocation and a marker to represent my location. I have at the moment code from ionic's documents geolocation implemented but does not seem to be doing anything. The one time I did get the geolocation to show it broke the code for the other markers on the map. I have been unsuccessful in implementing both multiple map markers + Geolocation together. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { MarkerDataService } from '../service/marker-data.service';
declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-marker',
  templateUrl: './all-marker.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-marker.page.scss'],
})
export class AllMarkerPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('map',{static:true}) mapContainer: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  markerData = [];

  constructor(
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
    private markerSerivice: MarkerDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

     }).catch((error) => {
       console.log('Error getting location', error);
     });

     let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
     watch.subscribe((data) => {

     });

    this.markerData = this.markerSerivice.getMarkers();
    this.displayGoogleMap();
    this.getMarkers();
  }

  displayGoogleMap() {
    const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.175471, -7.162739);

    const mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      disableDefaultUI: false,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  }

  getMarkers() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
    for (let _i = 0; _i < this.markerData.length; _i++) {
      if (_i > 0) {
        this.addMarkersToMap(this.markerData[_i]);
      }
    }
  }

  addMarkersToMap(marker) {
    const position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
    const fishingMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position, title: marker.name });
    fishingMarker.setMap(this.map);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your browser's Geolocation HTML5 feature to show the geographic location of a user or device on a Google map. A sample implementation can be found in [Maps JavaScript API documentation.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

This can be integrated with Ionic 4. For example on your `displayMap()` function you can just add these:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    console.log(pos);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pos,
      map: map,
    });
    map.setCenter(pos);
  });
```

I hope this helps!